# Select the optimal number based on conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

This is my minimal dataset:

```
df=structure(list(ID = c(3942504L, 3199413L, 1864266L, 4037617L, 
2030477L, 1342330L, 5434070L, 3200378L, 4810153L, 4886225L), 
    MI_TIME = c(1101L, 396L, 1140L, 417L, 642L, 1226L, 1189L, 
    484L, 766L, 527L), MI_Status = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Stroke_status = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Stroke_time = c(1101L, 396L, 1140L, 417L, 
    642L, 1226L, 1189L, 484L, 766L, 527L), Arrhythmia_status = c(NA, 
    NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA), Arrythmia_time = c(1101L, 
    356L, 1122L, 7L, 644L, 126L, 118L, 84L, 76L, 5237L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, I have mainly 2 types of variables "_status" and "_time".

I am preparing my dataset for a survival analysis, and "time" is time to event in days.

But the problem arrives when I try to create a variable called "any cardiovascular outcome" `(df$CV)` That I have defined as the following:

```
df$CV = NA
df$CV <- with(df, ifelse(MI_Status=='1' | Stroke_status=='1' | Arrhythmia_status== 'TRUE'  ,'1', '0'))              
df$CV = as.factor(df$CV)
```

The problem I have is with selecting the optimal time to event. As now I have a new variable called `df$CV`, but 3 different "_time" variables.
So I would like to create a new column, called `df$CV_time` where time, is the time for the event that happened first.
There is a slight difficulty in this problem though, and I put an example:

If we have a subject with `MI_status==1`, `Arrythmia_status==NA`, `stroke_status==1` and `MI_time==200`, `Arrythmia_time==100`, `stroke_time==220` --> the correct time for `df$CV` would be **200**, as it is the time for the earliest event.

However, in a case where `MI_status==0`, `Arrythmia_status==NA`, `stroke_status==0` and `MI_time==200`, `Arrythmia_time==100`, `stroke_time==220` --> the correct time for `df$CV` would be **220**, as it is the time for latest follow up is 220 days.

How could I select the optimal number for df$CV based on these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be one approach using `tidyverse`.

First, you may want to make sure your column names are consistent with spelling and case (here using `rename`).

Then, you can explicitly define your "Arrhythmia" outcome as `TRUE` or `FALSE` (instead of using `NA`).

You can put your data into long form with `pivot_longer`, and then `group_by` your `ID`. You can include the specific columns related to MI, stroke, and arrhythmia here (where there are "time" and "status" columns available). Note that in your actual dataset (where you use `glimpse` - it is unclear what you want for arrhythmia - there's a pif column name, but nothing specific for time or status).

Your cardiovascular outcome will include status for MI or Stroke that is 1, or Arrhythmia that is `TRUE`.

The time to event would be the `min` time if there was a cardiovascular outcome, otherwise use the censored time of latest follow up or `max` time.

Let me know if this gives you the desired output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rename(MI_time = MI_TIME, MI_status = MI_Status, Arrhythmia_time = Arrythmia_time) %>%
  replace_na(list(Arrhythmia_status = F)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(starts_with("MI_"), starts_with("Stroke_"), starts_with("Arrhythmia_")), 
               names_to = c("event", ".value"), 
               names_sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(
    any_cv_outcome = any(status[event %in% c("MI", "Stroke")] == 1 | status[event == "Arrhythmia"]),
    cv_time_to_event = ifelse(any_cv_outcome, min(time), max(time))
  )
```

**Output**

```
        ID any_cv_outcome cv_time_to_event
     <int> <lgl>                     <int>
 1 1342330 TRUE                        126
 2 1864266 TRUE                       1122
 3 2030477 FALSE                       644
 4 3199413 FALSE                       396
 5 3200378 TRUE                         84
 6 3942504 TRUE                       1101
 7 4037617 FALSE                       417
 8 4810153 TRUE                         76
 9 4886225 FALSE                      5237
10 5434070 FALSE                      1189
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This solution gives me an error: Error: Can't combine `date_0` <character> and `height_0` <double>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 72 rows [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25, 26, ...]. 
2: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 3 rows [62, 63, 64].

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I have updated the post with glimpse output (no data as it is confidential sorry!)

Comment: @Lili See edited answer. You can specify which columns to use with `pivot_longer`. For MI and stroke this looks like it should work. But I don't see `arrhythmnia_time` and `arrhythmia_status` in your dataset, just `Arrhythmia_pif`.